# How do you pickle a python object and retain member variable values when loading the pickle from a seperate python instance?

Tags: python, pickle

I want to be able to pickle an object which has an object as a member variable (while keeping the member object's properties). For example, consider the following files:

*foo.py:*

```py
class some_settings:
    setting_1 = 'Default'

class foo:
    my_settings = some_settings()
```

*main.py*

```py
import pickle
from foo import foo

if __name__ == '__main__':
    x = foo()
    x.my_settings.setting_1 = 'New Value'
    with open('out.p', 'wb') as fh:
        pickle.dump(x, fh)
```

Running `python main.py` generates `out.p`. However if I open a python intepreter and run the following code:

```py
import pickle
x = pickle.load(open('out.p', 'rb'))
print(x.my_settings.setting_1)
```

The output is:
`Default`

Is it possible to pickle 'x' in main.py so that setting_1 is 'New Value' when unpickling?

Answer (score 0):

Pickle won't store the class attributes of objects you pickle.  Did you really want `my_settings` to be shared by all instances of `foo`?  You called it a member variable.  Perhaps you wanted this:

```
class some_settings:
    def __init__(self):
        self.setting_1 = 'Default'

class foo:
    def __init__(self):
        self.my_settings = some_settings()
```

Comment: Yes, I guess I misspoke when I called it a member variable. I am dealing with 'parameters' in a package called `luigi`. Luigi parameters are defined in the class scope.(https://luigi.readthedocs.io/en/stable/parameters.html)